# Can a new Cytoscape ListSingleSelection tunable be created and rendered based on another ListSingleSelection tunable

Tags: cytoscape

I have a ListSingleSelection, as shown below:
@Tunable(description = "Domain", gravity = 1)
public ListSingleSelection domainTypes;
I want to create and render another ListSingleSelection based on the domainTypes.getSelectedValue(), say categories.

I've tried listenForChange on categories and when the selectionChanged event gets fired, I want to either repopulate the initial categories list, or recreate it based on the selected domain type.  The following does change the possible values, but the actual JComboBox on the panel does not get updated values.  Can this be done using tunables?

ex:

```
public class ExpTask extends AbstractTask implements RequestsUIHelper {
@Tunable(description = "Domain", gravity = 1)
public ListSingleSelection<String> domainTypes;

@Tunable(description = "Categories", listenForChange = "domainTypes", gravity = 2 )
public ListSingleSelection<String> categories;
    
private TunableUIHelper helper;

public ExpTask(ExpTaskFactory expTaskFactory) {
    super();
    domainTypes = new ListSingleSelection<>(ResourceManager.getDomains());
    categories = new ListSingleSelection<>(RangeResourceManager.getCategories(domainTypes.getSelectedValue());

    domainTypes.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(ListSelection<String> source) {
                System.out.printf("Selection changed: %s\n",domainTypes.getSelectedValue());
                categories.setPossibleValues(ResourceManager.getCategories(domainTypes.getSelectedValue()));
                
                if (helper != null)
                    helper.update(this);

                List<String> values = categories.getPossibleValues();
                values.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));
                
            }
            @Override
            public void listChanged(ListSelection<String> source) {
                System.out.printf("List changed\n");
           }
    });
```

...

As described, while using the ListChangeListener<> as coded I was able to change the set of values in the List, but am unable to see the changed values in the list in the GUI panel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you can do it by using getters and setters rather than exposing the public value.  So your code would look something like:

```
public ListSingleSelection<String> domainTypes;
@Tunable(description = "Domain", gravity = 1)
public ListSingleSelection<String> getdomainTypes() { return domainTypes; }
public void setdomainTypes(ListSingleSelection<String> dTypes) {
   domainTypes = dTypes;
   // Change categories values
}
```

You may also need to do something similar for the categories tunable, but that might not be necessary.